# A fallacy on finite vector integration

Tags: vectors

I was given:
If $
\vec r(t)=
     \begin{cases}
       2\hat i-\hat j+2\hat k, &\text{when}\; t=2\\
       4\hat i-2\hat j+3\hat k, &\text{when}\; t=3\\ 
     \end{cases}
$
then show that $\int_2^3\left(\vec r.\dfrac{d\vec r}{dt}\right)dt=10$.

Almost in every book, we find $\int\left(2\vec r.\dfrac{d\vec r}{dt}\right)dt=\vec r^2+\vec c$. Here my problem arises. What does $\vec r^2$ mean? Again on finite integration,
$\int_2^3\left(\vec r.\dfrac{d\vec r}{dt}\right)dt=\left[\dfrac{\vec r^2}{2}\right]_2^3$. So what will be the value of $\vec r^2(2)$ or $\vec r^2(3)$? Also if the value exists, is the integral really a vector function?

Comment: Certainly $\vec r^2 = \vec r \cdot \vec r = |\vec r|^2$.

Comment: Your vector valued function $\vec{r}$ isn't defined when $t\notin \{2,3\}$ so your integral doesn't have any meaning. It turns out that $\int_{t=a}^{t=b}\bigg(2\vec{r}\cdot \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} \bigg)dt=\|\vec{r}(b)\|^2-\|\vec{r}(a)\|^2$ by recognizing that $\int_{t=a}^{t=b}\bigg(2\vec{r}\cdot \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} \bigg)dt$ is the work done by the conservative vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\Big<2x,2y,2z\Big>$ which has potential function $\vec{f}(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ on an object moving along the path $C:=\{\vec{r}(t):t\in [a,b]\}$ transversed from $\vec{r}(a)$ to $\vec{r}(b)$.

Comment: @user429040 this is what i m given in text book